# Does EclipseLink/JPA have a plugin framework for modifying generated SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, eclipselink

Background: One thing that always messes ORM users up is `null` in SQL is treated very differently that 99% of programming languages, mainly `null == null` is `true` nearly everywhere but `null == null` is `false` in ANSI SQL.

EclipseLink *does not* transform bound parameters that are null to proper `IS NULL`, and instead makes the `WHERE table.field = null` mistake.

SQL has a null safe comparison operator: https://twitter.com/gabidavila/status/1101987501923811328

We'd like to somehow change the generation of the SQL so it always uses the `<=>` operator in the where clause. Is there a facility in EclipseLink to do this? Could we extend one of the dialects somehow?

The alternative is writing something like this for *every single comparison*, yikes.

```
(agentRef = :agentRef OR agentRef IS NULL AND :agentRef IS NULL)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can specify a DatabasePlatform class, and within it add any operators you need. See the SQLServerPlatform initializePlatformOperators method as an example of how specific operators are set for the SQLServer DB. You would want to override the addOperator(simpleRelation(Equal, "=", "equal")) with what ever operator can be used for your database.

Comment: Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can give you credit? Thank you!

Comment: Done, though it isn't a great answer. I'll see if I can come back and expand it sometime later, or feel free to post your own solution as the answer - detailed specifics you end up using are more likely to help someone more then mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a DatabasePlatform class, and within it add any operators you need. See the SQLServerPlatform initializePlatformOperators method as an example of how specific operators are set for the SQLServer DB. You would want to override the addOperator(simpleRelation(Equal, "=", "equal")) with what ever operator can be used for your database.